# Looking of a value in blessed hash

Tags: perl, hash, sdk, vmware

I am a begginer in Perl an i am trying to get à value from à blessed hash.

The value is ip adresses, i tried that with no success

```
print $vm->guest->ipStack->dnsConfig->ipAddress;

print $vm->guest->ipStack{dnsConfig}{ipAddress};
```

```
$VAR1 = [
    bless( {

        "ipRouteConfig" => bless( {

            "ipRoute" => [

                bless( {
                    "gateway" => bless( {
                        "device" => 0,
                        "ipAddress" => "10.*******"
                    }, 'NetIpRouteConfigInfoGateway' ),
                    "network" => "0.0.0.0",
                    "prefixLength" => 0
                }, 'NetIpRouteConfigInfoIpRoute' ),

                bless( {
                    "network" => "1***********",
                    "gateway" => bless( {
                        "device" => 0
                    }, 'NetIpRouteConfigInfoGateway' ),
                    "prefixLength" => 23
                }, 'NetIpRouteConfigInfoIpRoute' ),

                bless( {
                    "prefixLength" => 32,
                    "network" => "10**************",
                    "gateway" => bless( {
                        "device" => 0
                    }, 'NetIpRouteConfigInfoGateway' )
                }, 'NetIpRouteConfigInfoIpRoute' ),

                bless( {
                    "prefixLength" => 32,
                    "gateway" => bless( {
                        "device" => 0
                    }, 'NetIpRouteConfigInfoGateway' ),
                    "network" => "1***********5"
                }, 'NetIpRouteConfigInfoIpRoute' ),

                bless( {
                    "prefixLength" => 4,
                    "gateway" => bless( {
                        "device" => 0
                    }, 'NetIpRouteConfigInfoGateway' ),
                    "network" => "224.0.0.0"
                }, 'NetIpRouteConfigInfoIpRoute' ),

                bless( {
                    "gateway" => bless( {
                        "device" => 0
                    }, 'NetIpRouteConfigInfoGateway' ),
                    "network" => "255.255.255.255",
                    "prefixLength" => 32
                }, 'NetIpRouteConfigInfoIpRoute' ),

                bless( {
                    "prefixLength" => 64,
                    "network" => "fe80::",
                    "gateway" => bless( {
                        "device" => 0
                    }, 'NetIpRouteConfigInfoGateway' )
                }, 'NetIpRouteConfigInfoIpRoute' ),

                bless( {
                    "prefixLength" => 128,
                    "network" => "fe80::",
                    "gateway" => bless( {
                        "device" => 0
                    }, 'NetIpRouteConfigInfoGateway' )
                }, 'NetIpRouteConfigInfoIpRoute' ),

                bless( {
                    "prefixLength" => 8,
                    "network" => "ff00::",
                    "gateway" => bless( {
                        "device" => 0
                    }, 'NetIpRouteConfigInfoGateway' )
                }, 'NetIpRouteConfigInfoIpRoute' )
            ]

        }, 'NetIpRouteConfigInfo' ),

        "dnsConfig" => bless( {
            "dhcp" => 0,
            "searchDomain" => [
                "france"
            ],
            "hostName" => "HOST",
            "ipAddress" => [
                "10.60****",
                "10.6*****",
                "10.8*****"
            ],
            "domainName" => "france"
        }, 'NetDnsConfigInfo' )

    }, 'GuestStackInfo' )
]
```

Comment: What version of the vmware sdk is this? Do you have the documentation? Can you please [edit] your question and add the code that produces Data::Dumper output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever you have dumped is an array, not a hash. You need to show the call to `Dumper` for us to help you properly

Also, since this is a structure of blessed objects, ***you should be using their methods to access information***, not going by the "back door" and messing with the data structure directly. Unfortunately `GuestStackInfo` and `NetDnsConfigInfo` are VMware classes and not one of the standard Perl types so I can't suggest what method calls may be appropriate

Here are some notes

- The structure referred to by `$VAR1` is a one-element array containing a `GuestStackInfo` object
- The `GuestStackInfo` object contains a `NetIpRouteConfigInfo` object and a `NetDnsConfigInfo` object. I assume you are interested in the latter as you say *"The value is ip adresses"*, and the nearest hash key is `ipAddress` in the `NetDnsConfigInfo` object
- The `ipAddress` element is reference to an *array* of IP address-like strings

To access this array you would write

```
my $addresses = $VAR1->[0]{dnsConfig}{ipAddress};
```

and then to print them all out, use

```
print "$_\n" for @$addresses;
```

But *please take note* of my initial comments -- you should be using method calls and not poking around the data structure like this. Is there any documentation for those classes?

Comment: It works thank you.
I will look for documentation classes.